# Проблема с импортом данных SQL Server (база данных ФИАС)

Tags: импорт, dbf, sql-server

Вопрос можно ли как то автоматизировать импорт данных и маппинг типов? Например задать глобально, что все поля **varchar** преобразуются в **nvarchar**, а **23** в **date**?

Возникла проблема при импорте файлов *.dbf базы данных **ФИАС** в SQL Server. В таблица строки в форме varchar, плюс есть типы данных, которых нет в сервере (загадочный тип 23, соответствующий date). Сейчас, если заметь 23 на дату (что бы вообще возможно было выполнить импорт не словить ошибку) и импортировать таблицу, то данные вместо кириллических символов содержат знаки вопроса. Однако, при импорте можно настроить маппинг для одной таблицы (нажать кнопку изменить), где заменить 23 на дату, а varchar на nvarchar. Тогда все работает. Однако там порядка 440 таблиц и проделывать такую операцию вручную очень не хочется.

Comment: а как импортируете, какими средствами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автоматизировать можно, есть два пути, но оба потребуют трудозатрат, первый вариант настроить загрузку через SSIS, второй написать свою программку, которая будет обрабатывать и загружать данные в БД (пример могу дать).